# Unknown or broken timezone error for America/Phoenix

Tags: timezones

In General settings, local time is shown as equivalent to (the correct) UTC time.
[image]

No other settings are shown below the error and there is no Save Changes button.

In logging, I see the following, when I `grep` for timezone in a list of options with `wp option list | grep -i zone`:

```
PHP Warning:  timezone_open(): Unknown or bad timezone (America/Phoenix) in /var/www/union_made_sites/shirts/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5228
Warning: timezone_open(): Unknown or bad timezone (America/Phoenix) in /var/www/union_made_sites/shirts/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5228 
timezone_string America/Phoenix
```

Here are the results of a test file that contains the following php code:

```
<?php
require_once("../../../../wp-load.php");
echo date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
?>
<p>
<?php 
echo current_time('mysql'); 
?>
<p>
<?php
echo "This is GMT Offset:";
echo get_option('gmt_offset');
?>
```

[image]

I'm on Ubuntu, and I'm using `/etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini` to configure `mod_php`. I've set date.timezone explicitly in this file as follows:

```
date.timezone = "America/Phoenix"
```

I can confirm this particular `.ini` file is loaded via `phpinfo()`:
[image]

None of the plugins that are active are associated with calendars or scheduling.

In the `wp_options` table of the database, the `timezone_string` option has a value of `America/Phoenix`, but `gmt_offset` is an empty string.

Updating the table and setting `gmt_offset` to `-7` does nothing to improve things, aside from showing the correct local time in the General settings screen; `wp-cli` still throws the same error, the warning regarding "technical difficulties" displays, and the bottom half of the General settings screen does not appear.

Answer (score 2):

When I began troubleshooting this issue, I viewed the lack of a value for `gmt_offset` as the culprit, and considered the server to be solid. But after I updated the gmt_offset value in the database and the error persisted, I knew I'd been mistaken.

An admin had posted to a WP forum indicating that, despite having a valid timezone, things were amiss. His issue was circular soft-linking of timezones (`America/New_York` linked to `EST`, which itself was a softlink that linked back to `America/New_York`). Upon reading that, I'd confirmed that this wasn't the case on my own server.

However, coming back to checking over the system, I noticed that when I compared permissions of the timezone files (yes, it's always permissions) on another  environment (which was working fine), I noticed this discrepancy between the working environment (top)...

```
]# ls -alh /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Phoenix 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Aug 31 13:40 /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Phoenix -> ../SystemV/MST7
]# ls -alh /usr/share/zoneinfo/SystemV/MST7
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 353 Jul  4 14:46 /usr/share/zoneinfo/SystemV/MST7
```

... and the problem server...

```
]# ls -alh /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Phoenix
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul  4 14:46 /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Phoenix -> ../SystemV/MST7
]# ls -alh /usr/share/zoneinfo/SystemV/MST7
-rwxrw---- 1 root root 353 Jul  4 14:46 /usr/share/zoneinfo/SystemV/MST7
```

`chmod 644` and problem resolved.